# read less text css changes when there is less data

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the read more read less based on the height when there is more  data the read more and read less is working fine. but when there is less data the read less text is shifting up Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lakshmipriya001/Lz0cjeof/7/)
how to solve this issue.

```js
$(".show-more a").on("click", function() {
  var $link = $(this);
  var $content = $link.parent().prev("div.text-content");
  var linkText = $link.text();
  $content.toggleClass("short-text, full-text");
  $link.text(getShowLinkText(linkText));
  return false;
});

function getShowLinkText(currentText) {
  var newText = '';
  if (currentText.toUpperCase() === "READ MORE...") {
    newText = "Read less...";
  } else {
    newText = "Read more...";
  }
  return newText;
}
```

```css
text-content {
  line-height: 1em;
}

.short-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 2em;
}

.full-text {
  height: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.show-more {
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-container">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
  <div class="text-content short-text">
    voluptua.
  </div>
  <div class="show-more">
    <a href="#">Read more...</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The read more read less text should be at the bottom only how to solve this.

Comment: It only does that, because you have specified a height of 2em for the initial display, but your _one line of text_ doesn’t even require that much height. By switching to height:auto your element does not become larger here, but it actually shrinks in height. As soon as you try that with a proper example with more text, that problem disappears on its own … https://jsfiddle.net/Lz0cjeof/10/

Answer (score 0):

Added/Updated these styles

```
html, body, .text-container {
    height: 100%;
}
.text-container {
position: relative;
}
.show-more {
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```js
$(".show-more a").on("click", function() {
  var $link = $(this);
  var $content = $link.parent().prev("div.text-content");
  var linkText = $link.text();
  $content.toggleClass("short-text, full-text");
  $link.text(getShowLinkText(linkText));
  return false;
});

function getShowLinkText(currentText) {
  var newText = '';
  if (currentText.toUpperCase() === "READ MORE...") {
    newText = "Read less...";
  } else {
    newText = "Read more...";
  }
  return newText;
}
```

```css
html, body, .text-container {
    height: 100%;
}
.text-container {
position: relative;
}
.text-content {
  line-height: 1em;
}

.short-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 2em;
}

.full-text {
  height: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.show-more {
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-container">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
  <div class="text-content short-text">
    voluptua.
  </div>
  <div class="show-more">
    <a href="#">Read more...</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you but i have solved using the min height and max height

Comment: Ok.. No issues :) Just wanted to answer it as it was a nice ques.

Comment: @ Nandita Arora Sharma can u pls tell me if the height extend then the read more read less has to come

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
var status = "less";

function toggleText()
{
    var text="Here is some text that I want added to the HTML file";

    if (status == "less") {
        document.getElementById("textArea").innerHTML=text;
        document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerText = "See Less";
        status = "more";
    } else if (status == "more") {
        document.getElementById("textArea").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerText = "See More";
        status = "less"
    }
}
```

Comment: @CBroe i need with less data also

Comment: you can fixed size of string after that "see more" will display